# regarding python objects and their methods

Tags: python, text-based, adventure

I am currently trying to code a text-based adventure in pure python. Therefore I have a Room class which looks kinda like this (shortened):

```
class Room1(Room):

    def __init__(self):

        Room.__init__(self)
        self.init_objects()
        self.description = """Looks like a living room. There's a lamp, a 
                              cupboard, and
                              a door to your right. On the floor, there's a carpet."""
        self.door_state = 1
        self.carpet_state = 0
        self.images = [(text-based images)]

    def init_objects(self):

        self.objects = {"door" : Door1(),
                        "frontdoor" : FrontDoor(),
                        "carpet" : Carpet(),
                        "lamp" : Lamp1(),
                        "clock" : Clock(),
                        "escritoire" : Escritoire(),
                        "booklet" : Booklet(),
                        "screws" : Screws(),
                        "trapdoor" : TrapDoor()}

    def update_image(self):

        IMG_MAPPER = {(0, 0, 0) : 0,
                      (0, 0, 1) : 1,
                      (1, 0, 0) : 2,
                      (1, 0, 1) : 3,
                      (1, 1, 1) : 4,
                      (1, 1, 0) : 5,
                      (0, 1, 1) : 6,
                      (0, 1, 0) : 7}
        key = (self.objects["door"].state, self.objects["carpet"].state)
        self.img = img_mapper[key]
```

My problem is with the Room's update_image() method. I need a mapper to be stored there to figure out the right image according to the object's states (opened / closed), and if I put this mapper at the start of the method, this dict is read and constructed by python everytime the method is called, is that right? So should I rather store this mapper dict as an instance variable like self.img_mapper_dict = {(0, 0, 0) : 0, ...}?

Any ideas on that anyone perhaps?

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that the way your current code is structure, `IMAGE_MAPPER` would be assigned to every single time the `update_image()` method is called.

Now, since this is a static mapping that doesn't change over time, this is not a problem from a functionality standpoint - it's not like you're resetting a value that should be tracked between calls to `update_image()`.

Performance wise, in this particular case, the drawbacks will also be absolutely negligible.

But it would probably make sense from a purely logical standpoint to make this mapping a [**class attribute**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects):

```
class Room1(Room):

    IMG_MAPPING = {(0, 0, 0) : 0,
                   (0, 0, 1) : 1,
                   (1, 0, 0) : 2,
                   (1, 0, 1) : 3,
                   (1, 1, 1) : 4,
                   (1, 1, 0) : 5,
                   (0, 1, 1) : 6,
                   (0, 1, 0) : 7}

    def __init__(self):
        # ...

    def update_image(self):
        # ...
        self.img = Room1.IMG_MAPPING[key]
```

I'm recommending a class attribute instead of an instance attribute (or instance member) because that mapping is going to stay the same for all instances of `Room1` (right? I'm assuming every instance of `Room1` would have exactly the same layout, just different door states etc..). So it doesn't depend on any state of the instance, but it's a property of the class instead.

Also note that the class attribute is accessed differently: `Room1.IMG_MAPPING` instead of `self.IMG_MAPPING`. This also reflects the fact that it's not dependent on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think you're having is that `img_mapper` resets to the specified state **every time** `update_image()` is called. This is because the member function has its own scope, so when it is completed it deletes `img_mapper` and has to remake it next time the update function is called. Storing as a member variable would get rid of this problem.

Comment: So by 'member variable' you mean an instance variable as above? If not, can you specify?

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see is that your IMG_MAPPER dict has three-tuple keys. But you are accessing it by providing a two-tuple.

Comment: You're right... now there's 3, before there were 2... and when I was coding I encountered that problem I posted.